# Generate just custom tags with Doxygen

Tags: alias, doxygen

Is it possible to define custom tags and generate a documentation just of these tags in doxygen?

Comment: Just so you know this question isn't being entirely ignored - I think the answer is a simple "No".

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer... do you know an alternative tool ?

Comment: No, sorry.  I've never had that requirement.